# default virtual network interface

Tags: linux, networking, interface

I got a single ethernet connection to a network but with multiple ips.
Because of this, I am using virtual network interfaces like this:

```
auto intern
iface intern inet static
        address ...
        netmask ...
        gateway ...

auto intern:1
iface intern:1 inet static
        address ...
        netmask ...
        gateway ...
```

I need to configure which IP should be used by default for outgoing traffic.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the first sub-interface (`intern:1`) of the first interfac eis getting used as default device. It's a little bit weird that not just the primary interface (`intern`) is getting used.

If anyone has a fix for this, feel free to post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the option `-b src.ip.addr.ess`. For other tools, you need to at the manual to check for the right option. Also, `telnet` and `ssh` use the same option `-b`.

Comment: I am not looking for all those interface options, but for a way I can set the DEFAULT for all network-connected tools.

Comment: By default, each program/tool will use the "primary" interface address. I am not aware of a way to change this behavior globally unless you change this primary address.

Comment: How can I set the primary interface? What other effects could changing it have?

Comment: the primary interface is the first interface it finds on the subnet, otherwise its the first interface it finds which is on the subnet where the gateway is.

Comment: "It finds"... There must be a way on how to set this.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to configure which IP should be used by default for outgoing traffic.

Make it the first one listed in `/etc/network/interfaces` for that interface.

Example:

```
iface intern inet static
    address 198.51.100.30 # This one is it
```

Comment: This does not work. The second one (out of three) is getting used.

Comment: OK, then please edit your question to provide a more realistic view of what your `interfaces` file looks like.

Comment: It it not that different, just `intern, intern:1 and intern:2` - `intern:1` is getting used